# Entity Framework Core Update PK

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core

Is it possible to update the the Primary Key of a table when using EF Core.

I have tried _context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand with UPDATE statement as well as using a stored Proc and no joy, db.SaveChanges() gives the following error

System.InvalidOperationException: 'The property 'Id' on entity type 'Simulation' is part of a key and so cannot be modified or marked as modified.'

This is a one off job that needs to be done, I have temporarily modified the foreign keys to ON UPDATE CASCADE.

Is it possible with EF or should I just use ADO?

Thanks

Comment: Are you using MS SQL Server?

Comment: Yes I am using SQL Server

Comment: EF does not allow to change value of PK once it was inserted in the database.